# When define a function (or method) in coffeescript, what's the difference between using ":" and "=" to separate the function name and parameter list?

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript

I can't find any reference in the document. Below are some examples.

```
func1 = (a, b = 4) -> b^a

func2: (a, b = 4) -> b^a

class ClassA
    constructor: (@a, @b = 4) ->

class ClassB
    constructor= (@a, @b = 4) ->
```

From my experience I always use `=`, however I found `:` has been used in several examples in some blog posts. Hope someone can help to clarify.

Comment: Just compile them and look at the output. It's quite obvious then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're quite different, as examining the code will show. For the first two functions:

```
func1 = function(a, b) {
  if (b == null) {
    b = 4;
  }
  return b ^ a;
};

({
  func2: function(a, b) {
    if (b == null) {
      b = 4;
    }
    return b ^ a;
  }
});
```

The first defines a function. The second defines an object with a function as a member value.

The second isn't terribly helpful (unless there's a pathological side effect in the function declaration) since it creates the object only discard it immediately afterwards.

The class examples are a little different, in that the first will create an actual constructor function, because [That's How CoffeeScript Does It](http://coffeescript.org/#classes). The second creates a variable *named* constructor, which is a pretty different thing.

```
var ClassA, ClassB;

ClassA = (function() {
  function ClassA(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b != null ? b : 4;
  }

  return ClassA;

})();

ClassB = (function() {
  var constructor;

  function ClassB() {}

  constructor = function(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b != null ? b : 4;
  };

  return ClassB;

})();
```

Comment: Notice that with classes only this particular example will create a constructor, because it uses the `constructor` property. Other properties can use the same notation and will up as prototype members (which `constructor` implicitly does)